# Android - How to Print 2D arraylist to screen after button press

Tags: java, android, arraylist

im new to developing for andorid, and I wanted to know how you print the contents of a 2D arraylist to the screen once a button is pressed. Not looking for anything too over complicated either. Once i can just print the data, thatll be brilliant. I have my method below which should print, the fixtures of the premier league. Just wanted to know how to print those fixtures now. The code itself for getting the fixtures is fine, its just i dont know how to print it out. Cheers guys!

```
//  View Remaining Fixtures
public void ViewFixtures(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> teamsOrPlayers, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> fixtures, Integer fixturesPlayedToDate) {

    TextView display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ViewRemainingFixturesButton);
    String message = "League is complete";

    if(fixturesPlayedToDate != fixtures.get(0).size()) {

        for(int i = fixturesPlayedToDate; i < fixtures.get(0).size(); i++) {

            int homeTeam = Integer.parseInt(fixtures.get(1).get(i));
            int awayTeam = Integer.parseInt(fixtures.get(2).get(i));
            String homeTeamStr = teamsOrPlayers.get(1).get(homeTeam - 1);
            String awayTeamStr = teamsOrPlayers.get(1).get(awayTeam - 1);

            display.setTex;
            display.setText(awayTeamStr);
        }

    } else {
        display.setText(message);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_remaining_fixtures);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh and ignore that display.setText stuff really, i just made an attempt at printing but i dont think it works! Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to log it LogCat:

```
private void logInfo() {
    for (ArrayList<String> arrayList : outerArrayList) {
        for (String s: arrayList) {
            Log.d("tag", s);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to see it on-screen:

```
private void displayInfo() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (ArrayList<String> arrayList: outerArrayList) {
        for (String s: arrayList) {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append('\n');
        }
    }
    String yourInfo = stringBuilder.toString();
    yourTextView.setText(yourInfo); // assumes your textEdit is multiline
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, but im kind of looking for the actual printing more than anything else! The iterations are fine, its just the easiest way to print them now....

Comment: I'd just use `Log` probably to see it in LogCat. Edited above*

Comment: Ive seen that LogCat alright, but lets say when i run the emulator and press my button....what comes up? Is it actually the content of the arrayList or the logs??

Comment: If you add the code I posted above inside your `onClickListener`, all of the items in your list will show up in LogCat. If you want everything on screen, that's a little different and more work (need to create a `TextArea` or something multiline, then append to it). Depends what you want.

Comment: Cheers! ya looks like im going to have to do th e everything on screen approach! Any idea how i would do it using TextArea and append??

Comment: Edited again. I haven't tested, but you should just be able to make your `TextView` multiline with `android:multiline="true"` in your layout.xml, then use the code above to iterate through, get the strings and append them to a builder, turn the builder into a string, then attach that string with setText. Give it a shot and let me know if it works.